# Negative look behind with something in the middle

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two types of strings. If a string contains `foo` first and later `bar`, it shouldn't be touched. If it contains only `bar`, then `bar`, should be replaced by `qux`.

- `"sometext foo someothetext bar somethirdtext"` shouldn't be touched
- `"sometext bar someothetext"` => `"sometext qux someothetext"`

It looks like I need to use negative look behind, but I can't get it working correctly. Currently, I have an expression:

```
str.gsub! (/(?<!foo)(.*)bar/), '\1qux'
```

However, it replaces `bar` to `qux` in both strings. I have a feeling that `.*` screws things up. I wasn't able to find a look behind example where look behind group doesn't precede matched group immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use variable length lookbehinds, you could just replace matches of `/(?<!foo.*)bar/` with `'qux'`.

Without support for variable length lookbehinds, you can really use a lookbehind at all because you can't know the position to start the lookbehind to find `foo`.  Here is how you can do it with a lookahead:

```
str.gsub!  (/\A(((?!foo).)*)bar/m), '\1qux'
```

Explanation:

```
\A           # match at the start of the string
(            # start capture group 1
  (            # start capture group 2, repeat 0 or more times
    (?!foo)      # fail if 'foo' can match here
    .            # match a single character
  )*           # end capture group 2
)            # end capture group 1
bar          # match 'bar'
```

This performs the negative lookahead `(?!foo)` at each character until we match `bar`, so it will not match strings where `foo` comes before `bar`.

The anchor to the beginning of the string is necessary because if you can start in the middle of the string it will just start the match immediately after the `f` in `foo`.  The multiline option is used so that the `.` character will match line breaks, not sure if this is necessary for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
if str.include? "foo"
  str = str.slice(0, str.index("foo")-1).sub("bar","qux") + str.slice(str.index("foo")-1, str.length)
else
  str = str.sub("bar","qux")
end
```

It'll replace any "bar"s before the first instance of a "foo" and then tack on the rest of the string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `flag` to keep track of whether there was a `foo` preceding.

```
flag = false
"sometext foo someothetext bar somethirdtext"
.gsub(/(foo)|bar/){flag = true if $1; flag ? $& : "qux"}
# => "sometext foo someothetext bar somethirdtext"

flag = false
"sometext bar someothetext"
.gsub(/(foo)|bar/){flag = true if $1; flag ? $& : "qux"}
# => "sometext qux someothetext"
```